# How to list TODO items from a file which is not added to Agenda file list in Emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

There's a opened org-mode file which is not added to agenda file list (don't want to). How could I list all the TODO items in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling `org-agenda`, press `<` to limit the results to the current file (even if this isn't an agenda file). See the [agenda page](http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-files.html#Agenda-files) in the manual for more information.